# How to configure JMS Connection and JMS Session pooling in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jms, ibm-mq

Tomcat doesn't have any built-in JMS connection pooling while connecting to IBM WMQ 7.

```
<Resource name="jms/jmsQCF" auth="Container"
            type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory" factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
            description="JMS Queue Connection Factory for sending messages"
             HOST="localhost" PORT="1421" CHAN="CHL.QM1" TRAN="1" QMGR="INPUTQM"/>
```

IBM WMQ version 6 used to provide connection and session pooling using its internal logic. But the later versions of WMQ 7 or 8 doesn't provide this functionality. For reference http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21665128

Is there a way we can implement JMS connection pooling is tomcat context.xml

Answer (score 0):

First off-- Are you really sure you need to do caching? Pre-mature performance tuning of Enterprise Messaging often leads to anger, hate, suffering and all the downside of the Dark Side.

That being said-- the Spring JMSTemplate allows you to configure levels of caching for Connection, Session or Consumer.  Be careful though-- if you use transactions, you don't want to share anything other than Connection.